# Twilio Studio - Send and Wait for Reply - Multiple

Tags: twilio, twilio-functions, twilio-studio

I am trying to define a period of time (lets say 10 minutes, that stores all responses after a certain widget), and then save all those replies into one variable. Is this possible to do with twilio studio?

**Example:**

BOT: [sends message]

//start time - 0 min

USER: [reply1]

USER: [reply2]

USER: [reply3]

//end time - 10 min

`finalString = reply1+reply2+reply3...reply i`

Then I'd like to send that via HTTP POST request (This part seems to be easy if the values are all stored). But I'd want the HTTP request to execute after the 10 minutes, if there is at least one reply.

Any Twilio Evangelists that could help me out?

Answer (score 0):

The [Twilio Send & Wait For Reply](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/send-wait-reply) widget has a parameter called "Stop Gathering After", which waits X number of seconds for a response, before heading down the No Reply path. The parameter does not accept liquid syntax, so it is isn't possible to subtract the remaining time from your 10 minute budget (should you receive a response to the first widget say 3 minutes in), to ensure all the currently captured responses are sent to your server for that 10 minute maximum collection time.

Comment: Can I have another Twilio Send & Wait For Reply to it, but not send anything? 

I just want to Wait for Reply after the first reply.

Comment: That’s what the widget does, it waits for a reply over the gather timeout period.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

That's not something Studio is set up to do. It is intended for back and forth conversation, not a waiting period.

If you want to store something up like this, you will need to build the solution yourself.